# How to dismiss a Tab Bar Controller and go back to previous view controller on click of button

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am building a flow like this

FirstViewController -> SecondViewController - > Tab Bar View Controller (consists of 1. ThirdViewController and 2. FourthVIewController)

I am opening Tab Bar View Controller as a pop up form the SecondViewController. However, when I run (self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)) on click of a button in ThirdViewController, it goes back to the FirstViewController.
I want to go back to the SecondViewController

Adding code.
This is how I open the tab bar view controller from my SecondViewController

```
let popupVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarVC") as! UITabBarController
    self.addChildViewController(popupVC)
    popupVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(popupVC.view)
    popupVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

And this is how I try to close the tab bar view controller form Third View Controller

```
  self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil))
```

Comment: Show us your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You added tabBarController in secondViewController as subView. So you need to remove that tabBarController view from super view.

For that, you need a tabBarController object.

```
self.tabBarController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: The problem persists. on doing the above, I am redirected to the FirstViewController. I want to go back to the SecondViewController

Comment: I have edited the answer based on your provided code, please check

Comment: This is not working anymore on `Swift 5` and `Xcode 11`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a navigation controller in your flow, so when you are in ThirdViewController use this:

```
if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second") as? SecondViewController {
    self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: This is not doing anything. The view remain there

Answer (score 0):

The below code was able to remove the tabview and take me back to the SecondViewController

```
self.tabBarController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
```

Answer (score 0):

Switching to other item on UITabBar, where 0 insert index of UTTabBar item:

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
```